# Homography from 3D plane to plane parallel to image plane

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have an image in which there is a calibration target (known geometry) in a scene (let's say a simple 2" x 2" square lying on a table). I would like to perform a perspective transformation (using `warpPerspective()`) so that resulting image is an orthogonal view of the table (as if the camera axis was parallel with the table normal). The standard procedure for computing a homography is from a general plane to a different general plane where at least 4 correspondences are known in two images of the same scene (using `getPerspectiveTransform()`). In this case where I only have one image, is the correct thing to do to simply "make up" a plane and force the correspondences to some arbitrary position on that plane? For example, in this this situation I would simply make correspondences between the 4 detected corners (A,B,C,D) in the image and four points of my choosing (which essentially just define the pixel->real world scale. For example, I could choose A' = (0,0), B' = (20,20), C' = (0,20), D' = (20,0) to indicate in the resulting image there are 10 pixels per inch. Of course I could choose any scale here, and I could also choose any position for the square target to land in the output (i.e. A' = (100,100), B' = (120,120), C' = (100,120), D' = (120,100) ).

Is this the "correct" way to do this? Is there a better way to compute a projective transform that looks directly at a plane defined by a set of points in the image known to be in the plane?

Comment: Hi David! Yep, I think that's correct. At least, I did exactly this and it worked pretty good.

Comment: @Miki Thanks! Just making sure I wasn't missing something, as I didn't see anyone explain this anywhere on the internet, which always seems odd.

Comment: Ah, ok, someone has explained it after all :) : "Perspective Correction using Homography" here http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this case where I only have one image, is the correct thing to do to simply "make up" a plane and force the correspondences to some arbitrary position on that plane?

Yes.

Note that `getPerspectiveTransform` in its present implementation requires exactly 4 correspondences. It finds a 3x3 perspective transform, which has 8 degrees of freedom (the [3,3] element is fixed 1), so it only needs 4 non-colinear correspondences, and any such correspondences will be enough. In contrast, `findHomography` uses RANSAC to deal with uncertainty and can figure out which of the correspondences should be *trusted* and which are *outliers*. If you prefer to stick to linear least squares, you could adopt `getPerspectiveTransform` to accept >=4 pairs.

However, if you apply a perspective transform that converts some distorted square target `T` onto a perfect square, this will only make planes that are coplanar with `T` also line-parallel. Other planes (e.g., perpendicular to `T`) will not be line-parallel after transform.

If you want to remove the perspective, i.e., change the projection to be **orthographic**, you can't do it with a perspective transform alone. You'd also need to know the depth of the objects in the scene, then project it onto the plane without perspective.

Comment: a) In general the Direct Linear Transform method can take any number of *known* correspondences and use them all to compute the "best" matrix in a least squares sense (versus determining which correspondences to treat as "valid" with RANSAC) - is this not what `getPerspectiveTransform()` does? b) The transformed image will be "orthographic" for points on the plane of interest, right?

Comment: (a) Yes, `getPerspectiveTransform` computes the linear transform in the least squares sense, but in its current implementation, it requires exactly 4 correspondences. It'd be straightforward to modify it to accept any number >= 4.  See: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b3b434e221b99a237b989cfbf90ffe6e6af6fab1/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L6453   (b) Yes.